# How can I write a letter in my xml file?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Hello I have this triangle that I did with xml on Android Studio :

```
<item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="135"
            android:pivotX="7%"
            android:pivotY="65%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                                  <solid
                    android:color="@color/blue" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
        </item>
```

And what I want is to put a letter at the right of the triangle. How can I do this ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put text in the drawable itself.

What you could do is have your text as a text view and set its background as the drawable.

Or create a button and set its background to your drawable and set the text with the `setText()` method.

Comment: Nearly on the correct path. You can use the drawable as a *compound drawable* (typically, on the left or on the right side). And set the text normally (xml or Java)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

Make a `triangle.xml` and put it into your drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="135"
        android:pivotX="7%"
        android:pivotY="65%">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

And then make an `imageView`, put the triangle as a background and a `textView` on its side all wrapped inside a `linearLayout` with orientation horizontal.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/triangle"/>

<TextView
    android:text="A"
    android:textSize="100dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

Comment: The ImageView is **superfluous**. You can use a *compound drawable*, instead. And have the drawable **inside** the TextView.

Comment: That's correct, but I guess it depends on the control he wants to have on the image and on the text.

Comment: By using *compound drawables*, he can change both individually by code.